# Why does Firefox constantly open files and directories?

Tags: firefox

It concerns me that Firefox is constantly opening its own directory over and over again for no apparent reason. This is obviously bad for mechanical disk drives. Here is an example of the file accesses:

[image]

As you can see from the log, Firefox is opening its own directory, then doing a "FileBothDirectoryInformation" call on its own executable. There is no reason I can see why a program needs to read the attributes on its own EXE file three times a second. The EXE file is not changing.

Anybody know what is going on here? Is this just some kind of developer mistake or what?

Comment: Are you really using Firefox 18.0.1?

Comment: @DavidPostill No, that is just the name of the directory from the original install. Whenever Firefox upgrades, it continues to use the same directory.

Comment: Ah, OK was just wondering. I didn't think you would be ;)

Comment: Is this output from ProcessMonitor? If not what program is it? I'm trying to repro.

Comment: @DavidPostill it is from FileMon

Comment: Ah. OK. Replaced by [ProcessMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). Can you try with ProcessMon and see what you get?

Comment: I can repro but I've no idea what it's doing :/

Comment: Why obviously bad? Is your operating system so bad that it's not able to handle a file cache? If so, please switch to Linux.